# Windows driver model for Smart Card driver

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-10, driver, wdk

I want to rebuild old drivers for Smart Card under VS2015 (WDK 10). 
Old drivers designed for WDK 6 (no solution file, just makefile). As I understand according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/develop/creating-a-driver-from-existing-source-files I should create new solution based on corresponding driver template. Could You help with selecting proper driver model?

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/choosing-a-driver-model there are 3 types of it:

- Device Function Driver
- Filter Driver
- Software Driver.

I am not completely sure which I should select. In VS 2015 there are several templates under "Windows Driver" which seems looking appropriate to my task:

- Package:

  - WinUSB INF Driver Package
- WDF (UDMF/KMDF):

  - Kernel mode driver (KMDF)
  - User Mode Driver (UMDF V2)
- Legacy:

  - Empty WDM Driver
  - User Mode Driver (UMDF V1)

What information from source code could help me to select correct driver model and corresponding template?

Comment: Search in your code if WdfDriverCreate is used or any function starting with Wdf is used?

Comment: I found that creating 2 projects: Empty Static Driver Library for Drivers and Empty WDM Drivers seems appropriate to my drivers. 
Another question is how to resolve error: "C1083 Cannot open include file: 'suppress.h':No such file or directory".